# Property assignment expected. This expression is not callable. Type {} has no call signatures. (how to solve this?)

Tags: node.js, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I wanted to update a badge count in a chat room using cloud function trigger which is a nested map.
I'm updating badges in the frontend without any issue but I want the create a cloud function for this to reduce frontend workloads.
but when I tried to pass a dynamic variable as field/key, the compiler is not happy and it's giving me an error.

[image]

the expected output should be like this

[image]

Backtick doesn't work so I tried to change the backtick to double quote to be able to compile, but this was the output which is not what i want.

[image]

anyone knows how to make this work? please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its syntax issue, missing `[` & `]`.
it should be `` { [`badgeCount.${receveid}`]: fire.... ``.